# ES6 - Finding data in nested arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

In ES6 using `find` or `filter` I'm quite comfortable iterating through to find an element in an array using a value.

However, I'm trying to get a value from a parent array based upon a value from a nested array.

For example, in this data structure:

```
products: [
  {
    id: 01,
    items: [
      {
        id: 01,
        name: 'apple'
      },
      {
        id: 02,
        name: 'banana'
      },
      {
        id: 03,
        name: 'orange'
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 02,
    items: [
      {
        id: 01,
        name: 'carrot'
      },
      {
        id: 02,
        name: 'lettuce'
      },
      {
        id: 03,
        name: 'peas'
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 03,
    items: [
      {
        id: 01,
        name: 'eggs'
      },
      {
        id: 02,
        name: 'bread'
      },
      {
        id: 03,
        name: 'milk'
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

If I know the `name` or `id` of the object `milk`, is there a way to find out the id of the element it's nested within?

Currently I have this:

```
products.find((product) => {
  product.find((prod) => {
    return prod.name === 'milk';
  });
});
```

Which only returns the object containing `milk`.

Comment: I think this is a good question; a suggestion for improvement would be to make the `products:` example shorter to make it easier for the reader to scan through (and shorten the length of the question).

Answer (score 100, accepted):

You have to return something from the callback of the outer `find`. In fact, for the inner iteration you shouldn't use `find` but rather [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) that returns a boolean for whether an element matching the condition exists within the arrray:

```
products.find((product) => {
  return product.items.some((item) => {
//^^^^^^
    return item.name === 'milk';
  });
});
```

or in short:

```
products.find(product => product.items.some(item => item.name === 'milk'));
```

Then check whether `find` found something (not `null`!) and get its `.id`, the result should be `03`. Alternatively, you can `filter` for the products containing milk as an item and then map all the results to their id:

```
products.filter(product =>
  product.items.some(item => item.name === 'milk');
).map(product =>
  product.id
) // [03]
```

Comment: That makes sense - I hadn't seen `some` before.. but using this, how would I return the id of the outer element? For example, for the item `milk` the containing element has an id of `3`. Thanks!

Comment: just quick note, the `some` should happen on `product.items`, not on `product` directly

Comment: @Toby the code Bergi gave you will find your object and all you have to do is call `.id` on it: `const yourId = products.find(product => product.items.some(item => item.name === 'milk')).id`

Comment: what if i want to get array index?

Comment: @Kakajann Just use [`findIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) instead of `find`!

Answer (score 18):

I know you mention ES6, but in this case (and if you want to return the inner object) I believe it's better using `for`/`of` instead of `map`/`reduce`/`find`:

```
for (let p of products) {
  for (let i of p.items) {
    if (i.name === 'milk') return i;
  }
}
```

Comment: This seems like the cleanest solution (for both readability and performance). This is one of the few cases where functional programming isn't a good fit for the problem.

Answer (score 12):

Another approach:

```
products
  .map((category) => category.items)
  .flat()
  .find((product) => product.name === 'milk');
```

Comment: to make it more shorter, instead of map() & flat() just use flatMap()

Answer (score 8):

***UPDATE***

As Ricardo Marimon commented, reduce does not break so it keeps searching over the array, So with that in mind as I don't like to use for loops imperative way of programming, its possible to break early from a reduce by mutating the used array, but that would also be bad, so instead its possible to make a copy and mutate the copy instead too.

```js
// slice creates a copy of products
return products.slice(0).reduce((prev, product, i, arr) => {
    console.log(i);
    const findItem = prev || product.items.find(item => item.name === 'milk');
    if (typeof findItem !== 'undefined') arr.splice(1); // ejects early
    return findItem;
}, undefined);
```

```js
const products = [
  {id: 1, items: [
    {id: 1, name: 'apple'},
    {id: 2, name: 'banana'},
    {id: 3, name: 'orange'}
  ]},
  {id: 2, items: [
    {id: 1, name: 'carrot'},
    {id: 2, name: 'lettuce'},
    {id: 3, name: 'milk'}
  ]},
  {id: 3, items: [
    {id: 1, name: 'eggs'},
    {id: 2, name: 'bread'},
    {id: 3, name: 'peas'}
  ]}
];

const findItem = products.slice(0).reduce((prev, product, i, arr) => {
    console.log(i);
    const findItem = prev || product.items.find(item => item.name === 'milk');
    if (typeof findItem !== 'undefined') arr.splice(1); // ejects early
    return findItem;
}, undefined);

console.log(findItem);
```

***OLD***

The accepted answer didn't do it for me because I wanted the result of the inner find, using both it always gave me the result of the outer filter/find, and I had to use the resulting array to find the value again.

So instead I used reduce with short-circuit to get the inner result.

```js
// undefined as the initial value is necessary, otherwise it gets the first value of the array instead.

return products.reduce((prev, product) => prev || product.items.find(item => item.name === 'milk'), undefined);
```

```js
const products = [
  {id: 1, items: [
    {id: 1, name: 'apple'},
    {id: 2, name: 'banana'},
    {id: 3, name: 'orange'}
  ]},
  {id: 2, items: [
    {id: 1, name: 'carrot'},
    {id: 2, name: 'lettuce'},
    {id: 3, name: 'peas'}
  ]},
  {id: 3, items: [
    {id: 1, name: 'eggs'},
    {id: 2, name: 'bread'},
    {id: 3, name: 'milk'}
  ]}
];

console.log(products.reduce((prev, product) => prev || product.items.find(item => item.name === 'milk'), undefined));
```

Comment: Thanks, Gustavo! Been scouring the web for a solution to get the inner find. You're awesome!

Comment: Beware that this way continues to search for the item even after one is found. The reduce function can't break. The solution by @ariel does break upon finding.

Comment: Thanks Ricardo Marimon by pointing out that problem, I updated the answer to fix that by using two "hacky" ways of using reduce instead of for loops.

Answer (score 1):

To get the item directly without doubling back to get the id/object:

```js
const products = [
  { id: 01,
    items: [ { id: 01, name: 'apple' },
             { id: 02, name: 'banana'},
             { id: 03, name: 'orange'}]},
  { id: 02,
    items: [ { id: 01, name: 'carrot' },
             { id: 02, name: 'lettuce'},
             { id: 03, name: 'peas'   }]},
  { id: 03,
    items: [ { id: 01, name: 'eggs'  },
             { id: 02, name: 'bread' },
             { id: 03, name: 'milk'  }]}
 ]

    let found;
    for ( const category of products ){
        found = category.items.find( item => item.name == "milk" )
        if ( found ) break
    }
    console.log( found ) 
    // == { id: 3, name: 'milk' }
```

Answer (score 1):

If there is not a convenient way to get the data you need from the datastructure you have, then start by changing the datastructure:

```js
// find once
products
  .flatMap((category) => category.items)
  .find((product) => product.name === 'milk');

// find often
const productsByName = Object.fromEntries(
  products.flatMap(
    (category) => category.items.map(
      (item) => [item.name, item]
    )
  )
);
productsByName['milk']
```

flatMap is the same as doing a map first followed by a flat of 1 level (the default). Object.entries transform [['key', 'value']] into {key: 'value'}

Comment: I like the idea of using flatMap. Easy and Works perfect!