# Iterate over JSON child array to find specific Id

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json

I am making an API call:

```
const idVal = 59
APIGet(resource, params)
        .then((res) => {
            console.log(res.data.body)
            setData(res.data.body)
        })
```

console.log(res.data.body) returns:

```
Array [ {…} ]

0: Object { Id: 978, UniqueHash: "uZIYvh", Title: "testval", … }
​​
Id: 978
​​​​
Title: "Title for product"
​​
UniqueHash: "uYvh"
​​
organizers: Array [ {…}, {…} ]
​​​
0: Object { Id: 1, Name: "Store", Description: "store description", … }
​​​
1: Object { Id: 59, Name: "Conference", Description: "conference text", … }
​​​
length: 2
​​​
<prototype>: Array []
​​
<prototype>: Object { … }
​
length: 1
```

I would need to get the 'organizers' by Id (59 in this example). How would I go about adapting the code to go through the organizers.Id and to only get the organizer data based on a specific Id?
I guess its iterate over the res.data.body.organizers to see if organizers.Id === const idVal?

Please note that the length of the main object is always 1, while 'organizers' can be many.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ES6 - Finding data in nested arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40025718/es6-finding-data-in-nested-arrays)

Comment: `console.log(res.data.body[0].organizers.find(organizer => organizer.Id === 59) `